# How to set up top image on application page in iOS11 App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios11

Just found out that some applications have top image with nice parallax effect in the App Store in iOS11.

Example:

[image: yandex.taxi top image example]

Is it possible to provide custom image for my application or it must be featured by Apple at some way? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your app must be featured by the App Store team. You can't set it by yourself.

[App Product Page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/product-page/)
[Promote app link](https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/promote/)